# Через определённое время после создания записи изменить её тип

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите как можно реализовать.После добавления записи на сайте WordPress,нужно через время изменить её статус на черновик, через сутки например.Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> После добавления записи на сайте WordPress,нужно через время изменить
>   её статус на черновик

Можно с пом плагина https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/

Comment: спасибо,но хотелось бы кодом увидить

Comment: Плагинофобия? Это лечится изучением матчасти. Но нет ничего проще: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/post-expirator/tags/2.3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте такой код в function.php вашей темы:

```
// Добавляем хук на сохранение поста
add_action( 'save_post', 'action_save_post' );
function action_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // Если это ревизия, то ничего не делаем
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || get_post($post_id)->post_status !== 'publish' ) {
        return;
    }
    // Регистрируем одиночное событие через 30 минут.
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 60 * 30, 'change_post_status_event', array( $post_id ) );
}

// Добавляем хук на событие
add_action( 'change_post_status_event', 'change_post_status', 10, 1 );
function change_post_status( $post_id ) {
    // Удаляем действие по сохранению поста, чтобы избежать зацикливания
    remove_action('save_post', 'action_save_post');

    // Создаем данные поста
    $post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    // Обновляем пост
    wp_update_post( $post );

    // Возвращаем действие по сохранению поста
    add_action('save_post', 'action_save_post');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам.Буду пробовать код.

Comment: А чего его пробовать) он оттестирован мною и работает

Comment: Ну я имею ввиду,буду пробовать не плагин, а код ВАШ! :)

Comment: А я про код и говорю - я его проверил на своем тестовом сайте. Он работает )

Comment: Хорошо!Это отлично.

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться другим пользователям, ищущим ответ на похожий вопрос.